# Regular expression to parse delimited, qualified string

Tags: regex, csv

I have been asked for a regular expression to parse a delimited string using .NET. The delimited string may also have double quote qualified content.

I have come up with the following expression:

```
(?<=^|\,)(.*?)(?=\,|$)
```

which feels like it is almost there. Running this expression against the following test data:

```
,test 1, "{test""100,000.0"" 2}", test 3,
```

yields:

```
<empty>
test 1
"{test""100
000.0"" 2}"
test 3
<empty>
```

So, it looks like it is working except for the double quote qualified content.

I have found searched and tried some other suggestions but have not found anything that worked.

I am not capturing them, but it would be OK for the delimiters and qualifiers to be included if that makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex captures your target terms:

```
(?<=^|,)((?:,(?!(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)|[^,])*)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/4W3V6ku22y), showing capture of:

```
<empty>
test 1
"{test""100,000.0"" 2}"
test 3
<empty>
```

This captures non-commas or commas (using a look-ahead) that are followed by an *even* number of quotes (commas within quotes are followed by an *odd* number of quotes).

Comment: Thank you, this appears to do exactly what I needed. Now I will try to break this down and learn from it.

Comment: @user1723105 explanation added to answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the regular expression to negate the ',' and extract the strings in between consecutive ','.

you can use the expression "([^,]*)".

I verified the same in https://regex101.com/

Comment: I think I was already capturing the strings between consecutive commas, that was not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split by this

```
,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/yX8zV8/1

If you want to capture use

```
((?:[^,]|,(?!(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$))+)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/yX8zV8/2

Comment: He doesn't want to split. He wants to capture.

Comment: @Bohemian added the method to catprue as well

Comment: Except [your regex doesn't capture the empty columns](http://rubular.com/r/vIY5X2GQXi).

Comment: vks your second expression worked great in terms of capturing the field content qualified or unqualified. But as Bohemian pointed out it did not capture the empty columns.

Comment: @user1723105 Do u want empty matches ??

Comment: Yes I would like to capture each field empty or not